# Run Program Escape Sequence Putty

Tags: windows, shell, putty, remote, escaping

Run windows calculator in windows from the Unix command prompt environment!

```
>echo \\calc
```

How would I accomplish this same task in putty?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [AljexClient](http://code.google.com/p/aljex-client/) if you're still looking for the solution.
It's a PuTTY fork where one of the added features is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really hackish solution, but you could always use metasploit payloads to get VNC connections or do whatever you like.  It's really going around your backside to get to your elbow, but it works.

And it's free.

Comment: Interesting solution. However this happens to be on a network with mandatory PCI compliance. I would need something a little more stable and non-patchable per say.

Comment: does using at with a time in the immediate future not solve the problem?